# How can I submit my form without encrypting the inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I am submitting the form I am using enctype="multipart/form-data" to get the file but the other inputs are showing undefined. how can I get the file and inputs value? together. FYI, I tried setting the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" for formenctype="multipart/form-data" for the file input only but I couldn't get the file value.

```
<form action="/jobs" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate='novalidate'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="first name*" class="form-control" name="fName" formenctype=""
                        required>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenName" name="test">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="last name*" class="form-control" name="lName" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Postion*" class="form-control" name="postion" required>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="email*" class="form-control" name="email" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="phone number*" class="form-control" name="phone" required>
                    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Where do you live*</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea name="remark" placeholder="Remark / Cover Letter" class="form-control text-area"
                        rows="7"></textarea>
                    <div class="lastcontrol">
                        <input type="file" accept=".pdf" name="file" required>
                        <button type="submit" class="send-btn">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I am using node js for the server-side and the post request is:

```js
const upload = multer({
    limits: { fileSize: 1000000 },
}).single('file');


router.post('/jobs', async (req, res, next) => {

    const obj = {
        fullName: req.body.fName + ' ' + req.body.lName,
        Postion: req.body.postion,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        country: req.body.country,
        Letter: req.body.remark,
        file: req.body.file,
        test: req.body.test
    }

    console.log(obj);
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('there is an err')
        }
        const buff = req.file.buffer
        console.log(buff);

        res.send('done')
    })

})
```

this code is to get the information from the form and the file which will be pdf and send it by email using SendGrid API, I could get the file and sending it through email but the other values are shown as undefined.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean "get the file and inputs value?" In what context and via what language? Show us your server-side code which handles the submission.

Comment: On the server-side it's no longer a POST. But File.